# google cloud compute engine storage option images are getting created automatically and resulting into billing

Tags: google-cloud-platform

In our application, we use only google cloud for storing and retrieving files. Otherwise, we do not use any compute engine or virtual machines or any other options under Google cloud. I see that images are getting created automatically under the storage option of Compute engine menu of Google cloud like this

[image]

Any idea as to why this might be happening? Tried raising a call with Google Cloud support team but no closure answers.

Comment: FYI customer support questions are off-topic here. Please see [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions on Stack Overflow?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Answer (score 0):

Those are [public OS images](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images?_gl=1*19r1541*_ga*MTgyMjQ2NTYzMC4xNjI0ODk3MjEx*_ga_WH2QY8WWF5*MTcxMTExOTE4Ny4zMDcuMS4xNzExMTE5MTk4LjAuMC4w&_ga=2.174886434.-1822465630.1624897211). You are not being charged for that if that is the concern.

Comment: OK. However, there is charge costed to the account for these images still ( though negligible )

Comment: To answer that question properly, you need to go to menu> billing > link billing account > view details on reports > filter by SKUid > plug here https://cloud.google.com/skus/?hl=en  . After doing that you will get a better understanding of what is being charged and how to control it.

Comment: Also you can do this, please click on the 3 bars to the left of show deprecated images > select created by > if you see your project ID that means it was created by the project ID, if you see Debian, Canonical or windows then it is not you. Though negligible you should not be charged if not created by the prject ID/you.